# Can you privaite or direct message members here?

Tags: support

Something that is pretty common across forums is messaging. I've looked of peoples profiles and can't find it anywhere.

Is that something that isn't used here? If so, how? If not, why?

Comment: Here's the main stack exchange meta discussion on the issue, which explains some of the "why not": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can message people via [the chat interface](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photography), using @ in front of their user name so that it shows up in their SE inbox. This is not private however; there is no private messaging system at present. This isn't a forum in the traditional (internet) use of the word.

Comment: Yeah, as I thought. Sorry if I implied I thought this was a forum, I was just saying generally. I'm not so much interested in being private but more so just contacting a member. Thanks for that, at least I know how to contact someone.

Comment: Oh, no offence taken, I don't care what anyone calls it, just pointing out the difference.

Comment: I don't think the @name thing works if the user hasn't participated in chat recently. (Moderators can use @@name to notify people regardless, but that's not available generally. Mods can also send private messages for admin-related issues.)

Comment: No, @ works regardless; my first visit (of a pathetic few) to chat was driven by an oblique reference to me using the @-syntax in somebody else's conversation. I don't even think it was deliberate, but it showed up in my inbox anyway.

Comment: @mattdm I think you're right about the chat @ feature. Unless it's changed since Stan's experience (or was a glitch) or you just haven't got the notification yet (you're usually pretty responsive) I @'d you in chat and hadn't heard anything. Also, the predictive name didn't appear either but did for the others. It was only to thank you very much for the bounty. I appreciate doing your own work a lot more now. :)

Answer (score -1):

There is provision for an email address on users' profile pages if they wish to use it.
 I guess that many don't wish to do so.
eg mine is [**here **](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6263/russell-mcmahon) and has the email address shown.

Um. I just looked at a few other profiles and do not see an email field at all. Maybe it only shows if you fill it in and/or enable it when completing your profile.

Comment: Yep. That's pretty common for profiles too. To only display your email address to your own profile. Though some sites will give you the option to display it. But I'm not that interested in emailing people. I've been using the chat option. Cheers though!

Comment: E-mail addresses are only available to moderators, and even then only after clicking an additional link. The website field shows to everyone. And of course you can put your address in your profile if you really want.

Comment: The e-mail field is private. If you want to publicise it, put it in the editable text part of your profile.